# std::atomic::store can't be called in ctor initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

When I was trying to call std::atomic::store in initialization list, I got following compiler error:
`g++ -std=c++11 test_function_call_in_ctor.cc`

`test_function_call_in_ctor.cc: In constructor ‘TestA::TestA()’:
test_function_call_in_ctor.cc:7:17: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
   TestA() : run_.store(true) {
                 ^
test_function_call_in_ctor.cc:7:17: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘.’ token`

source code as below:

```
class TestA {
  public:
    TestA() : run_.store(true) {
      cout << "TestA()";
      if (run_.load()) {
        cout << "Run == TRUE" << endl;
      }
    }
    ~TestA() {}
  private:
    std::atomic<bool> run_;
};
int main() {
  TestA a;
  return 0;
}
```

Any idea on this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer list specifies the constructor arguments of the members. You cannot use a member function as you tried. However, `std::atomic<T>` has a constructor taking a `T` value as arguemnt:

```
TestA(): run_(true) { ... }
```

Since the object is under construction it can't possibly be used by another thread at that time, i.e., there is no need to use `store()` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Dietmar. Perhaps I didn't describe my question clear enough. The first version I tried as you mentioned, however, it failed on threads data race check, but if I put run_.store(true) within ctor, it would pass data race check and it's found out initialization list can't directly use ': run_.store(true)'.  I think your answer make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because `run_` hasn't been constructed. You should call its constructor in the initializer list:

```
TestA() : run_(true) {}
```